# Increments of different values based on click location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want for a variable to increment according to where i click. And then be able to reduce by the amount of where it is clicked. Yet the first increment isn't stored in z so when i make the second increment it doesn't add with the first increment, just posts the second increment. How can i make this increments work? Here is the code:

```js
$(".pesqopcao").click(function() {
  var color = $(this).css("background-color");
  var z = 0;
  if (color == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' || color == 'white') {
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    z += (this.id * 1);
    document.getElementById("z").innerHTML = z;
  } else
  if (color == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' || color == 'blue') {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    z - (this.id * 1);
    document.getElementById("z").innerHTML = z;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="101" class="pesqopcao">101</div>
<div id="601" class="pesqopcao">601</div>
<div id="901" class="pesqopcao">901</div>

<div id="z"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your variable outside of the jQuery click event for it to persist between clicks.

Also, typo on line 11: You're subtracting from `z` but not setting it to anything. Should be `z -=` instead of `z -`.

```js
var z = 0;

$(".pesqopcao").click(function() {
  var color = $(this).css("background-color");
  if (color == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' || color == 'white') {
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    z += (this.id * 1);
    document.getElementById("z").innerHTML = z;
  } else if (color == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' || color == 'blue') {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    z -= (this.id * 1);
    document.getElementById("z").innerHTML = z;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="101" class="pesqopcao">101</div>
<div id="601" class="pesqopcao">601</div>
<div id="901" class="pesqopcao">901</div>

<div id="z"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1-value of z as it is an id so string parseInt it.
```

2-declare variable as a global (without var keyword) outside function.
3- $(this).id is not defined use attr method of jquery api

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 z=0;
$(".pesqopcao").on('click',function() {
var color = $(this).css("background-color");
if (color == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' || color == 'white') {
  $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
  z+=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
  document.getElementById("z").innerHTML = z;
}else{
if (color == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' || color == 'blue') {
  $(this).css("background-color", "white");
  z-=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
  $("#z").text(z);
}
}
});
});
```

```css
.pesqopcao{background-color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="101" class="pesqopcao">101</div>
<div id="601" class="pesqopcao">601</div>
<div id="901" class="pesqopcao">901</div>
<span id="z"></span>
```